# Disable Paste for UITextField inside UIAlertController's configurationHandler

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I present a UIAlertController where there is an embedded UITextfield for a certain type of input.

```
    passwordPrompt.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(textField: UITextField!) in
        textField.placeholder = "Bestellmenge"
        inputTextField = textField
        inputTextField?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        inputTextField?.keyboardType = product.unitName == "KG" ? .decimalPad : .numberPad

    })
```

Normally when we want to disable "Paste" for a certain UITextField we need to create a subclass of UITextField  and override `canPerformAction` method.

How can I handle the thing with the given configurationHandler ?

Comment: This only achievable with a bunch of "hacky" solutions. You should create a custom alert view instead.

Comment: @the4kman Thank you. thats bad news for Friday afternoon =)